# Uncaught NSException when battery level changes

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a simple app that just shows the time and battery level. The time part works flawlessly, and I can monitor the battery level, but the battery indicator icon crashes the app when there are any changes to the device's battery. Here's the relevant code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true // Enable battery monitoring
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("batteryStateDidChange:")), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChange, object: nil) // Add battery state checker
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("batteryLevelDidChange:")), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChange, object: nil) // Add battery level checker
    // Get the battery level
    var batteryLevel: Int {
        return Int(UIDevice.current.batteryLevel * 100)
    }
    update()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true) // Start the timed scheduler
}
```

Here's the error:

```
2017-06-24 11:45:27.783761-0500 SimpleClock[1484:846193] -[SimpleClock.ViewController batteryLevelDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15dd15bc0
2017-06-24 11:45:27.785656-0500 SimpleClock[1484:846193] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SimpleClock.ViewController batteryLevelDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15dd15bc0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x181c65858 0x18043c528 0x181c72a6c 0x188815140 0x181c6af68 0x181b4ce5c 0x181bf3004 0x181bf25a4 0x181bf2308 0x181c74268 0x181b2a4e4 0x1826f32d4 0x1884abd60 0x1884abbc8 0x181ecdaf0 0x181beda68 0x181c0cbc8 0x181c0c370 0x181c09d80 0x181b28280 0x183639f94 0x1884d70f0 0x100da10e4 0x180919e40)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Do not post a link to your code. [Edit] your question with relevant code, as text.

Comment: The error message  *batteryLevelDidChange:]: unrecognized selector...* is pretty clear. The method is missing or the signature is wrong.

Comment: PS: use the native Swift `#selector` syntax. The benefit is you get the error at compile time.

Comment: Where's your `batteryLevelDidChange` method?

Answer (score 1):

The `-[SimpleClock.ViewController batteryLevelDidChange:]: unrecognised selector` error indicates that the `batteryLevelDidChange` function is missing in the code or as Vadian commented, the signature is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if condition` before adding the observer for `batteryStateDidChange:` selector. You can use `respondsToSelector:` method for this. This way you can make sure if the selector is implemented.

Also you need to implement the selector in your source file as I can't see it in your code, hence giving the `unrecognised selector` error.

Hope it helps!

Comment: `respondsToSelector:` is Objective-C legacy habit. In Swift the compiler can check target / action selectors at compile time.

Comment: I think we need to use it in Swift as well for backward iOS compatibility. But we can also use `?` in Swift for this purpose.

Comment: No, we don't need to check those things at runtime in Swift at all. If you use the recommended `#selector` syntax the compiler checks the corresponding method at compile time.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the correction. I will try `#selector` next time.